# Need to write where condition consists of 2 groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I want to write where condition in a SQL Server query which has following conditions:

1. Where paymentmode='Bank' and Status not equal to Paid
2. payment mode='cash' and sataus not equal to completed

How I can write these 4 condition b

Answer (score 1):

We put the sets of conditions in brackets. In the following either all the conditions in the first parenthesis must be met or all those in the second.

```
Where 
  (paymentmode='Bank' 
   and Status <> 'Paid')
Or
  (paymentmode='cash' 
   and status <> 'completed')
```

Comment: Generally we write `Status <> 'Paid'` rather than `not Status = 'Paid'`